# How to show Navigation button in MKPinAnnotationView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm looking for a way to add the little car button to the left of my annotation just like in the image.

[image]

I've seen similar implantations in apps other than Apple's. So far i can put a completely custom button there with the blue background and i have to put an image to make it look similar to those ones using

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
static NSString *reuseId = @"Location";
MKPinAnnotationView *view = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
if (!view) {
    view = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
    view.canShowCallout = YES;
    UIButton * leftButton = [[UIButton alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 47, 47)];
    [leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [leftButton setBackgroundColor:self.view.tintColor];
    [leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showRoute) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [view setLeftCalloutAccessoryView: leftButton];

}
view.annotation = annotation;

return view; 
}
```

but I was wondering if there is a public API that I can use to make this button look like the one on Apple maps and even make it's behavior easier to implement.

Comment: What's the problem with what you're doing? If you have it solved, what's the question?

Comment: I want to have the same icon as in the image, I want to know if this button is a system button, and if there is an easier way to implement it. Sorry if i didn't make my self clear on the question

Comment: I don't think it's a system button but nothing stops you from grabbing a screen shot and making an identical button. And that's going to give you a perfectly good result. Do file an enhancement request with Apple if you think they should be doing more to standardize this for you!